# Losing Cookies after succesful login

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I try to call a page after succeful login but it's redirect me to log out page

when i run the script everything works fine! i can login and save cookies, reuse cookies and get pages without any problem. 
but once the script finish and try to run it again and get another page with the same cookies, the website redirect me to logout page.

**here is my curl request**

```
$headers = ['User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36','Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3','Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/tmp/'.session_id());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/tmp/'.session_id());
if(!is_null($data))
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $exec;
```

Comment: It might not have been the issue of your coding. The cookie / session of the server might simply have expiration time.

Comment: One question, you're calling `session_id()` for the cookiejar file name. Can you perhaps try to hard code it so it's the same everytime?

Comment: i test it in mac/windows centos same result, yes the server have expiration time is 30 minutes